# Есть ли в owl carousel возможность просмотра текущего слайда?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Добрый день , есть ли в owl что то подобное:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, по первому поиску можно найти [такой](https://codepen.io/maer2k/pen/qPVWEd) пример:

```js
$('.slider').on('initialized.owl.carousel changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    if (!e.namespace)  {
      return;
    }
    var carousel = e.relatedTarget;
    $('.slider-counter').text(carousel.relative(carousel.current()) + 1 + '/' + carousel.items().length);
  }).owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true
  });
```

```css
.owl-item {
  background-color: #D2527F;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.owl-prev,
.owl-next {
  display: inline-block;
}
.owl-next {
  float: right;
}
.slider-counter {
  text-align: center;
}

.info {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 110px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<div class="slider owl-carousel">
  <div> Slide 1 </div>
  <div> Slide 2 </div>
  <div> Slide 3 </div>
  <div> Slide 4 </div>
  <div> Slide 5 </div>
</div>
<div class="slider-counter"></div>

<div class="info">
    <p>Owl carousel counter <a href="https://codepen.io/jovanivezic/pen/JXWOex" target="_blank">CSS solution</a></p>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```